# How can i show only the results that have an association in rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, where-clause, nested-includes

I am trying do a where statement that only brings up results that have that particular association.

For example:

A company has many statuses through company statuses. They can have multiple statuses that can be gold, silver, and/or bronze, or none at all. I am trying to have my results only return the companies that have a status (gold, silver, and/or bronze) and not the ones have no statuses.

Answer (score 0):

Your use case isn't very well articulated, but I *think* what you're wanting is to find Companies that have a status that matches a specified one:

```
Company.includes(:statuses).where('status.name = ?', params[:status_name])
```

That should give you the right query, assuming a Company `has_many :statuses`.

Comment: Sorry for not explaining more. I'll edit the question to fix it. What i am trying to do though is retrieve only companies that don't have any statuses. They could have gold, silver, and/or bronze, or they could not have any. I am trying to find any company that has at least one status.

Comment: I don't know if you can combine a join with an `is not null`. :/

Comment: Yeah, that's what makes it tough. I'm not sure how you'd do that. I feel like there has to be a way though. It can't be that uncommon.

Comment: Try `Company.includes(:statuses).where('status.somecolumn IS NULL')` and if that doesn't work, share the query it creates (in your log) and we can maybe go from there?

Comment: Well i think i figured it out. I can't really post the results though since i am not using that exact senario. I simplified it for the question. For my real code i have users that have companies that have dealer statuses. But i believe this works either way.

User.find(:all, :include => [:statuses], :conditions => ["statuses.id IS NOT NULL"])

Answer (score 0):

From the Ruby on Rails guide on Active Record Associations:

> ```
> 4.2.3 How To Know Whether There’s an Associated Object?
> ```
>
> To know whether there’s and associated object just check
>   association.nil?:
>
> if @supplier.account.nil?
>
> @msg = "No account found for this supplier"
>
> end

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#detailed-association-reference

Answer (score 0):

```
Company.joins(:statuses).select("DISTINCT(companies.id), companies.*, statuses.*")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an associative table called companies_statuses:

to retrieve all companies with at least one status

```
Company.where("EXISTS (select 1 from companies_statuses where companies_statuses.company_id = companies.id)")
```

to retrieve all companies with no status

```
Company.where("NOT EXISTS (select 1 from companies_statuses where companies_statuses.company_id = companies.id)")
```